# Why does this property not work inside the function?

Tags: angular

The problem is with slideIndex, inside the function I checked it with alert.  First its value is 0 then it is undefined and after that  `this.slideIndex++;` evaluates to NaN. Why this happens whats the workaround.
It is supposed to switch image every 2 seconds. Initially the image shows and after 2 seconds no image is shown because of that slideIndex issue.
The js part i took from here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

Works inside ng viewInit without the function call. Why does't the same work inside the function?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setInterval(()=>{
    var i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("xx");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      //@ts-ignore
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    this.slideIndex++;
    if (this.slideIndex > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}    
    //@ts-ignore
   slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   },2000)
  }
```

This one doesn't work.

```
export class ... {
    slideIndex: number = 0;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.startSlider();
      }

    startSlider(){
      var i;
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("xx");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        //@ts-ignore
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      this.slideIndex++;
      if (this.slideIndex > slides.length) {this.slideIndex = 1}    
       //@ts-ignore
      slides[this.slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      setInterval(this.startSlider, 2000);
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
 <section class="lazy slider">
        <div class="xx">
          <h1>dsdsdds</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home01.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="xx">
          <h1>dsfdsfdsfdsf</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home02.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="xx">
          <h1>sfdfdsfdsfdsf.</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home03.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line: `setInterval(this.startSlider, 2000);` When you call `setInterval` in that way the `startSlider` function gets a new scope which means that `this` no longer refers to your component. You need to explicity set the context of the function using the `bind` function on the provided method. Update to the following and it should work:

```js
setInterval(this.startSlider.bind(this), 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what to talk about first, but generally it's not angular way at all.

what you're trying to achieve is as simple as

```
// mySlider.component.ts
// ..
ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => this.update(), 2000); 
  // setInterval(this.update, 2000); won't work because you're passing the function body
}
update() {
  this.slideIndex++;
  if (this.slideIndex > slides.length) {
    this.slideIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

in html

```
<section class="lazy slider">
        <div class="xx" [style.display]="slideIndex === 0 ? 'block' : 'none'">
          <h1>dsdsdds</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home01.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="xx" [style.display]="slideIndex === 1 ? 'block' : 'none'">
          <h1>dsfdsfdsfdsf</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home02.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
        <div class="xx" [style.display]="slideIndex === 2 ? 'block' : 'none'">
          <h1>sfdfdsfdsfdsf.</h1>
          <figure><img src="theme/images/home03.jpg" width="509" alt="responsive websites" class="img-responsive"></figure>
        </div>
 </section>
```

still not angular way you better use `*ngFor` for the slides, but at least it uses the main feature angular was originally intending to solve.